# ImportError: No module named 'django'

Tags: django, ubuntu, apache2, django-admin

Estoy trabajando una aplicación en Django desde Ubuntu Server 16.0.4 LTS siguiendo este tutorial

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-django-applications-with-apache-and-mod_wsgi-on-ubuntu-16-04

Y me topé con ese error

ImportError: No module named 'django'

No sé si hice algo mal, les comparto mis rutas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es la configuración de mi archivo de apache

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    #ServerName www.example.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
    <Directory />
    Require all granted
    </Directory>
    Alias /static /home/proyeto/prueba/static
    <Directory /home/proyecto/prueba/static>
             Require all granted
        </Directory>
    <Directory /home/proyecto/prueba/prueba>
            <Files wsgi.py>
                    Require all granted
            </Files>
        </Directory>

    WSGIDaemonProcess prueba  python-home=/home/proyecto/prueba/entorno python-path=/home/proyecto/prueba
    WSGIProcessGroup prueba
        WSGIScriptAlias / /home/proyecto/prueba/prueba/wsgi.py
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Verifica si lo tienes instalado con el comando: ``pip list`` o si tienes alguna otra instalación de Python.

Comment: si está instalado hermano, tengo la versión 1.11.20

Answer (score 0):

Intentaste verificar sí tienes django instalado con `pip`, con el siguiente comando:

```
pip freeze
```

Esto mostrara todas las librerías que tienes instaladas en `python`. Sí `django` no aparece debes ejecutar:

```
pip install django
```

Lo que puede ser es que sí creaste un ambiente virtual con python debes activarlo, cuando esta activado cambiar el prompt de la consola de siguiente forma.

Pensemos en window (que es el S. O. que tengo ahora, es análogo para ubuntu), cuando abres el cmd (o una terminal) el prompt aparece esta forma:

```
D:\path1\path2>
```

Pero cuando inicias con el ambiente virtual:

```
(env) D:\path1\path2>
```

Sí te fijas aparece el nombre de una carpeta `env` que fue el nombre de que le dí al ambiente virtual, cuando activas debes instalar ahí `django` con `pip`. Para activar el ambiente virtual debes ejecutar el siguiente comando en ubuntu:

```
source path/venv/bin/activate
```

donde `venv` es el nombre que le diste al ambiente virtual cuando lo creaste. Cuando lo actives aparecerá el nombre de la carpeta en el prompt de la consola.